Safari and canvas' context lost
Apparently Safari (including the mobile versions) is the only mainstream browser that does not support the HTMLCanvasElement.contextlost and HTMLCanvasElement.contextrestored events. Does this mean the context would not ever lost on a Safari browser (or did Safari handled that case for you)? If not, how does one handle a context lost?

Ah you're in a "still image" case, right?. Do they really lose contexts for these? You're right listening for the event would be needed in that case. Missing a way to force that I can't really tell what they do. Trying to force an OOM through creating many canvases the page crashes, but so does it in the other browsers...

@Kaiido yes they do get lost, although I'm yet to find a way to stably reproduce it. I have experienced it for a few times on a mobile Chrome, when I switch the browser to the background and switch back later, the context might be lost already. That's why I'm trying to implement the repaint mechanism. I've not done a lot of test on Safari yet so can't say if it really happens there.
